# Convert Binary Data to Torch Tensor in Lua

Tags: lua, jpeg, binary-data, torch, luasocket

I have Lua code that downloads an image from a url using a luasocket:

```
local http = require('socket.http')
local image = require('image')

image_url = 'https://www.somedomain.com/someimage.jpg'
local body, code = http.request(image_url) -- body has jpg binary data
if not body then error(code) end -- check for errors
```

In order to read this image into a Torch tensor, I save it in a jpg file and read it using `image.load`:

```
-- open a file in binary mode to store the image
local f = assert(io.open('./temp.jpg', 'wb')) 
f:write(body)
f:close()

tensor = image.load('temp.jpg')
```

Is there a way to convert the binary jpg data to a torch tensor directly without doing a write-to-and-read-from the hard-drive? Something like:

```
tensor = CovertBinaryDataToTorchTensor(body)
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

See [image.decompressJPG](https://github.com/torch/image/blob/master/doc/saveload.md#res-imagedecompressjpgtensor-depth-tensortype).

You just have to pack your `body` string inside a ByteTensor first. This can be done by constructing this tensor with a [storage](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/storage.md#constructors-and-access-methods) which can set his contents with [string(str)](https://github.com/torch/torch7/blob/master/doc/storage.md#self-stringstr).

Comment: `torch.ByteTensor(torch.ByteStorage():string(_string_))`

Answer (score 0):

One potential solution is to use graphicsmagick.

```
local gm = require 'graphicsmagick'
local img = gm.Image()
local ok = pcall(img.fromString, img, body)
img = img:toTensor('float', 'RGB', 'DHW')
```

I found this example in https://github.com/clementfarabet/graphicsmagick/blob/master/test/corrupt.lua and I know that

```
local body, code = http.request(image_url)
```

will return `body` as a string. And, obviously if `pcall` returns false, the image was corrupt.